# Quick sorting array of arrays of chars in C

Tags: arrays, c, char, quicksort

I have been trying to implement a quick sort of array of arrays of chars in C but it's giving me a segmentation fault error that I am not able to debug. This is the code:

```c
int partition(char **a, int left, int right)
{
    int i, j;
    char pivot[16];
    strcpy(pivot, a[left]);
    i = left;
    j = right + 1;

    while (1)
    {
        do
            i++;
        while (i <= right && strcmp(a[i], pivot) < 0);
        do
            j--;
        while (strcmp(a[j], pivot) > 0);
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        char t[16];
        strcpy(t, a[i]);
        strcpy(a[i], a[j]);
        strcpy(a[j], t);
    }
    char t[16];
    strcpy(t, a[left]);
    strcpy(a[left], a[j]);
    strcpy(a[j], t);
    return j;
}

void quickSortChar(char **a, int left, int right)
{
    int j;
    if (left < right)
    {
        j = partition(a, left, right);
        quickSortChar(a, left, j - 1);
        quickSortChar(a, j + 1, right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char **arr = (char **)calloc(10, sizeof(char *));
    arr[0] = (char *)malloc(16);
    arr[1] = (char *)malloc(16);
    arr[2] = (char *)malloc(16);
    arr[0] = "patata";
    arr[1] = "berenjena";
    arr[2] = "alioli";

    quickSortChar(arr, 0, 2);
}
```

### Update 1

Using `strcpy` does not work either:

```c
int partition(char **a, int left, int right)
{
    int i, j;
    char pivot[16];
    strcpy(pivot, a[left]);
    i = left;
    j = right + 1;

    while (1)
    {
        do
            i++;
        while (strcmp(a[i], pivot) < 0 && i <= right);
        do
            j--;
        while (strcmp(a[j], pivot) > 0);
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        char t[16];
        strcpy(t, a[i]);
        strcpy(a[i], a[j]);
        strcpy(a[j], t);
    }
    char t[16];
    strcpy(t, a[left]);
    strcpy(a[left], a[j]);
    strcpy(a[j], t);
    return j;
}
```

### Update 2

I have solved the warning by moving up the declaration.

### Update 3

Fix `while (i <= right && strcmp(a[i], pivot) < 0);`

Comment: As asked recently, use `strcpy()` to copy a string. The `arr[0] = "patata";` etc overwrites the pointers that you allocated.

Comment: You also must provide a declaration to satisfy the forward reference to function `partition()` or move the function. Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: I have tried using strcpy and it does not work. I have also addressed the warning but with the same result.

Comment: You are allocating memory and immediately leaking it as you assign a static string; don't need `malloc`: `char *arr[] = { "patata", "berenjena", "alioli" };`, and you certainly don't need `strcpy`.

Comment: This just an example. In my real program I have the structure described in the question.

Comment: You are doing a lot of extra work; is there some reason you don't just sort the pointers like `qsort`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to do it but I do not get it to work: qsort(arr, 3, sizeof(char *), strcmp);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you check `i` didn't passed the length of `a` only after `strcmp(a[i], pivot) < 0` hence you reach `i=3` and then get dumped.

Change to

```
while (i <= right && strcmp(a[i], pivot) < 0);
```

I'd also suggest using `calloc` instead of `malloc` in order to initialize the `arr`

Comment: You are right but this does not solve the  issue :(

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado I've just run the code on my computer with no errors

Comment: Using calloc? or malloc?

Comment: I'm compiling with gcc -p t test.c && ./t

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado both, compiled with `gcc -Wall tmp.c -o tmp`

Comment: I have updated the  code just in case, but I'm still getting a segmentation fault :(((

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado that's not how you use `calloc`, google it.
Anyway, this https://www.codepile.net/pile/zWZazQY0 version, using malloc works just fine.